# Populating Combobox from remote server

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `combobox`, i need to populate data from the server. In the server side i have the following data to be displayed.

```
PersonID
PersonFName
PersonLName
```

In the combobox, i need to display the text as `PersonFName + PersonLName` (Like `James Smith`- This is what it will display in the drop down) , and when a user selects a record, I need to display the corresponding `PersonID` (Like Person with `PersonFName` and `PersonLName` has the PersonID of `1`) of that user.

I am unable to figure this out, here's my code

View :

```
{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id: 'personcombo',
                    readOnly: false,
                    selectOnFocus: true,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    store: 'Person'  
            }
```

Store :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.PersonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Person'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: 'person.php',
                    create: 'person.php'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'array'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Model :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'PersonID'
        },
        {
            name: 'PersonFName'
        },
        {
            name: 'PersonLName'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: What do you see right now? Is the main problem 'how to display combined fields'?

Comment: Yes you are right. i need to know how to display combined fields.

Comment: Look at the @Geronimo answer on how to create dynamic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is: how to display `PersonFName` + `PersonLName` in the combobox but keep the `PersonID` field as the value.

You should add a [converted](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) field which joins the first and last names in your data model and then make that one your combobox `displayField` config.

Though the other answer did bring up a good point that the defined store in your combo is `Person` but you are showing code for a store named `PersonStore`.

It would look something like this:

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'PersonID'
        },
        {
            name: 'PersonFName'
        },
        {
            name: 'PersonLName'
        },
        {
            name: 'PersonName',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.data.PersonFName + ' ' + 
                    record.data.PersonLName;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**Store:**

```
// changed to "Person" instead of "PersonStore"
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Person'
    ],

    model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'person.php',
            create: 'person.php'
        },
        reader: 'array'
    }
});
```

**View:**

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    id: 'personcombo',
    readOnly: false,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    store: 'Person',
    valueField: 'PersonID',
    displayField: 'PersonName' // the converted field

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox has 'Person' as the store, but I don't see you create a store called Person anywhere. Try `store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.PersonStore', {autoLoad: true})`.

You can also simplify your store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.PersonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Person'
    ],

    model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'person.php',
            create: 'person.php'
        },
        reader: 'array'
    }
});
```

Comment: I think store will get automatically created

Comment: I don't see how. He gave the store property a string which will use Ext.data.StoreManager to find a store with that id, but he never created such a store.

Comment: I never create stores manually in my project. Just define them and specify `stores:[]` array in controllers that use them. StoreManager will automatically create store when you call `Ext.getStore('storename')`

Comment: It's the defining them in a controller's stores property that creates them, not calling Ext.getStore (which is an alias for Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup). He's not doing that (that I can see).

Comment: You're kind of right... I was using not Ext.getStore() but controller.getStore which will create store if it doesn't exist.

Comment: It also gets called by the controller's constructor, so it will exist by the time you do anything with it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - can u point me to the ExtJs code that creates stores based on stores:[] array?

Comment: Yeah, it's rather convoluted, but (assuming 4.1.1): Controller's `constructor()` calls `this.createGetters('store', this.stores);` which creates a pre-argumented `getStore` call for each store passed in: `this[fn] = Ext.Function.pass(this['get' + type], [ref], this);` which is then immediately executed: `this[fn](ref);` The argument ref here appears to be left over from old code, as it's already passed because of its inclusion in the Ext.Function.pass call, and getStore only takes one argument.

Comment: It's for that reason that I always use `requires` instead of `stores`. I often have store types I will use, but do not want automatically instantiated.